# How to broadcast multiple videos on one Youtube channel

Tags: live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

Use case: I want to provide Live Stream option on my website & users can opt to live steam imp moments to their Network. i.e. multiple users can live steam the multiple videos at the same moment.

- Is it feasible to let multiple users live stream simultaneously via Youtube Live Stream API?
- If not Youtube API, is there any other reliable service provider?
- Mobile browser support is essential (lite weight solution)